# Finding the count of a word uppercase or lowercase

Tags: perl

I have to find how many times a word in a file appears, whether it is upper or lower case.  I used:

```
my %count;  

foreach my $line ( split "\n", $text )
{
   foreach my $word ($line =~ /(\w+)/g)
{
   $count{$word}++; 
}
}

print "'love' occurs $count{myword} times\n";
```

I thought that `(\w+)` would get upper and lowercase, but it did not.  I know I should alter the case when I add the value in the hash, but when I do, I still do not get the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

`\w` does match upper and lower case (and 0-9 and the underscore).  [lc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) is one way to disregard case.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = '
Here are words to count.
Words.  And now more words.
';

my %count;
while ($text =~ /(\w+)/g) {
    $count{lc $1}++;
}

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
print Dumper(\%count);

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          'and' => 1,
          'are' => 1,
          'count' => 1,
          'here' => 1,
          'more' => 1,
          'now' => 1,
          'to' => 1,
          'words' => 3
        };
```